# how to put comma in link_to

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Ideally I want some like this LastName, FirstName, how to put comma into the link ?

```
<%= link_to @name.first.LastName,@name.first.FirstName, management_show_path(:user_id => @name.first.id) %>
```

Comment: You should use snake case (`first_name`) instead of camel case (`FirstName`) for your attributes.

Comment: Anything you can take the `first` of should be named as a plural. The link text needs to be a single argument, e.g., use string interpolation. I would, however, wrap all that up in a model or decorator method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<%= link_to @name.first.LastName+ ','+ @name.first.FirstName, management_show_path(:user_id => @name.first.id) %>
```

Comment: oh... stupid me... how did I forget !!! :P, thanks for the help worked like a charm !

Comment: I'd *much* prefer string interpolation here. Better yet, a helper method. Better still, a decorator method.

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
<%= link_to "#{@name.first.LastName}, #{@name.first.FirstName}", management_show_path(:user_id => @name.first.id) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a helper method. Something like:

```
def user_name(user)
  [user.last_name, user.first_name].join ", "
end
```

and call it via:

```
<%= link_to user_name(@user), management_show_path(user_id: @user.id) %>
```